# jQuery dynamic table with select

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a dynamic table, in other words, a table where the number of columns per row

1. isn't necessarily the same as the other rows
2. can be changed live by the user

in every added column, there is contained a dropdown box which is filled using a database request.

I would like to be able to fill this dropdown once when the page loads, and not every time a column is added(it's for a calendar, so worst case: multiple times per row = 31*x).

I'm using jquery 1.9 and php 5.3 for my programming.
I've tried with JSON and $.post(), but this escapes too much of the needed slashes and quotes, and due to my version 5.3 of php, I can't use the "DO_NOT_ESCAPE_ANYTHING" constants provided in php 5.4+ (and yes, I know that that name isn't right, it's by heart)

So, heart of the question:

How do I use a combination of jquery and php to put a HTML -tag in a javascript variable to output on a jquery-handled button-click.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjc3y/3/

code:

HTML:

```
<form name="myform" id="myForm" action="#test">
    <div>
        <table id="persCalTable">
            <tr id="DAY_0">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="name" size="25" value="Enter your name here!" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button id="eventAdder">add event</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitter" />
    </div>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function addCellToRow(row, cell) {
    row.append(cell);
}

function expandCalendarTable(myObj) {
    var DATA = myObj.closest('tr').attr('id').slice(4); //data is the number after DAY_
    var selector = '#persCalTable #DAY_' + DATA; //selector is the table and the clicked row id
    var cellHiddenField = '<input type="hidden" name="status" value="New" />';
    var cellOtherData = "INSERT SELECT TAG HERE";
    var cell = cellHiddenField + cellOtherData;
    addCellToRow($(selector), cell); // add the cell to the row defined by the selector
    eve.preventDefault(); // stop the page refresh(if not in a form, this is not needed, when in a form, this is needed)
    //alert('Picked: ' + DATA);
}



$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitter").click(

    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($('#myForm').serialize());

    });
    $("[id^=eventAdder]").click(

    function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        expandCalendarTable($(this));
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have?

Comment: You need can create select once store it in var and when adding new column clone that var and append clone to new column.

Comment: I'd love to see what you mean with a fragment of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can have differing columns per row in an HTML table, if you have the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What you will end up with is a table with 3 columns, and in the second row the third cell will be empty and borderless. What you can do is use a seperate table for each row, set the widths as equal and calculate and set cell widths manually with jQuery.

As for the calendar. I would suggest you use JQueryUi, which has a great calender control or a similar library than going for a select. Either way, you can prepare the object ahead of time and store it in a variable. You will then have to use clone on it otherwise it will move to the last place you inserted it at.

```
$(function(){

    // Prepare the select (obviously yours would be more complicated)

    var select = $("<select>");
    <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count($optionValue); $i++ ) { ?>
    select.append($("<option value='<?php echo $optionValue[$i]?>'><?php echo $optionText[$i]?></option>"));
    <?php } ?>

    // Insert into relevant parts
    $("#insert1").append(select.clone());
    $("#insert1 select").attr("name", "select1");

    $("#insert2").append(select.clone());
    $("#insert2 select").attr("name", "select2");

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the clone. The calendar + table columns are allright. However, how would I fill the var select with information from a DB to be reused later? You can't easely put php variables in javascript variables IIRC

Comment: I have added some php code to my example to generate the selects from php. It's quite simple really just echo into the script.

Comment: I'll try this, though probably tomorrow.

Comment: "You can't easely put php variables in javascript variables IIRC" It is not an issue to send variables from php to javascript, since php will be executed first on the server and the resulting javascript sent to the client. If anything you would have problems if you wanted to say log raw php code to the console. `console.log("<?php dosomething(); ?>");` will not log `"<?php dosomething(); ?>` to the console but first try to execute dosomething.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TNG7y/ is a simple exection in what I need. Thank you for your answer, it was a great help :-D